# Prometheus (metric) relabel config with inverse regex match / negative lookahead

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Right now I'm scraping metrics from a Node Exporter. Some of the metrics which the Node Exporters exports have a `mountpoint` label.

I'd like to drop time series that have this label and **do not** match a regular expression. I tried using the `keep` action (as I'd like to keep time series that **do** match this regular expression) but this also drops all other metrics that do not have the `mountpoint` label.

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: ['mountpoint']
    regex: '(\/home|\/var\/domains)\/something.*'
    action: keep
```

I tried using the `drop` action too but this requires me to inverse the regular expression using a negative-lookahead (which isn't supported because Prometheus is written in Go of course).

What are my options in this?

**Important,** I do not have control over the way the Node Exporter is configured, thus I can't configure the Node Exporter itself to not export metrics for some specific mountpoint (if this is even possible).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then the following *should* meet your needs. I tested it in the [Relabeler](https://relabeler.promlabs.com/) online tool and seems to do what you want?

Using these relabeling rules:

```
- source_labels: ['mountpoint']
  regex: '(\/home|\/var\/domains)\/something.*'
  target_label: __tmp_keep_me
  replacement: true
- source_labels: [__tmp_keep_me]
  regex: true
  action: keep
```

The following (example) object labels would be kept:

```
mountpoint: "/home/something/"
job: "node"
fstype: "ext4"
```

While these would be dropped:

```
mountpoint: "/tmp"
job: "node"
fstype: "ext4"
```

Note that I used a tip Brian Brazil shared in the [Or in relabelling](https://www.robustperception.io/or-in-relabelling) article and adapted it.

Comment: It does not because the problem still exists that time series without the "mountpoint" label would get dropped as well. I didn't know about the "__tmp_" convention / relabeling technique so thanks for that!

Comment: Roger that. Maybe you wanna ask this in https://discuss.prometheus.io … I'm sure someone will have an answer there ;)

Comment: Will do that, thanks so much for the help! Really appreciate it a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `|` to the end of the regex, so it matches time series without `mountpoint` label:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [mountpoint]
  regex: '(/home|/var/domains)/something.*|'
  action: keep
```

Shameless plug (I'm the author of `vmagent`): [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) supports easier-to-understand-and-use construct for this particular case with `if` option:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- if: '{mountpoint=~"/home|/var/domains)/something.*|"}'
  action: keep
```

The `if` option may contain arbitrary [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabeling) for more details.